# Handler method first mapped, than not found

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

could you please help me to explain why my controllers' handler methods fail to correctly function, i.e. being correctly mapped during application upload, they are not found during operational phase, e.g. from logs

```
...
RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/searchModel],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String CLASS_NAME.METHOD()
...
[main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 16212 ms
...
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /searchModel
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/searchModel]
...
```

Is it some issue with missing configuration, or it goes deeper in my code ?

Controller's code

```
@Controller
public class SearchModelController {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private SearchModelDAO searchModelDAO;
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchModel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String METHOD()
    {
        return "searchModelForm.html";
    }
    ...
```

Besides methods and two @Autowired, there is not much in controller's code. All necessary imports are done.

Application main is defined with

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("CONTEXT.xml");
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
```

CONTEXT.xml is

```
<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="..., ..., ..."/> 
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
...
```

web.xml is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">
<display-name>...</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

The code compiles under Eclipse with Maven and produces WAR package. Then I put .war in apache webapps directory and start apache.

Thank you

Comment: As Nathan mentioned you need to include code in you question. Also please check that the searchModel is not POST. The mapped url by HandlerMapping is a GET method.

Comment: Provide details about you web context path, and the complete URL that you are trying to hit.

Comment: I try to hit http://localhost:8080/searchModel. What is "web context path" ?